# Why doesn't it print "1" when I hold down the left mouse button?

Tags: python

Why doesn't it print "1" when I hold down the left mouse button? There are no errors.

```
import time
import mouse

while mouse.is_pressed("left"):
    print("1")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Because when you start the program, the mouse *isn't* pressed, the loop condition *isn't* met, it skips right past the loop, and ends…? — I mean, *tell us*, what exactly are you doing and what exactly is happening?

Comment: You should make this printing as an event, and not a loop, because the loop ends since the mouse isn't pressed when the condition is checked the first time.

Comment: Okay, just to get up into that loop, you made me realize that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an infinite loop, like this:

```
while True:
    if mouse.is_pressed("left"):
        print(1)
```